# Return previous record for holiday/weekends

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

A table has stock name, values and effective date for the stocks and there wont be any entry for holidays/weekends. I would like to return a previous date record if I pass the range of dates contains holidays/weekends.

E.G.

Table name: Stock

```
    ID  Name    Value   EffectiveDate
    1   IBM 200.0000    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000
    2   IBM 201.4500    2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
    3   IBM 201.0000    2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    4   IBM 202.0000    2016-01-06 00:00:00.000

   SELECT Name, Value, EffectiveDate FROM Stock WHERE Name = 'IBM' AND  EffectiveDate >= '20151231' AND EffectiveDate <= '20160105'
```

The above query returns top 3 records but I would like to return the below results:

```
    Name    Value   EffectiveDate   ActualDate
    IBM 200.0000    2015-12-31      2015-12-31 
    IBM 200.0000    2015-12-31      2016-01-01 
    IBM 200.0000    2015-12-31      2016-01-02 
    IBM 200.0000    2015-12-31      2016-01-03 
    IBM 201.4500    2016-01-04      2015-01-04 
    IBM 201.0000    2016-01-05      2015-01-05
```

01/01/2016 to 03/01/2016 are holidays/weekends. I've a function which returns the previous date if I pass the holiday/weekend date. Could anyone help to write the query in SQL Server to achieve the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  value decimal(10, 4),
  EffectiveDate datetime
)
INSERT INTO @table
  VALUES (1, 'IBM', 200.0000, '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000')
  , (2, 'IBM', 201.4500, '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000')
  , (3, 'IBM', 201.0000, '2016-01-05 00:00:00.000')
  , (4, 'IBM', 202.0000, '2016-01-06 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @MinDate datetime = '20151231',
        @MaxDate datetime = '20160105';

WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @MinDate AS ActualDate
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, ActualDate)
    FROM Dates
    WHERE ActualDate < @MaxDate
)
SELECT [Table].name 
      ,[Table].value
      ,[Table].EffectiveDate
      ,[Dates].ActualDate
FROM Dates
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate) AS LastEffectiveDate
         FROM @table AS [Table]
         WHERE [Table].EffectiveDate <= Dates.ActualDate
     ) AS CA1
     INNER JOIN @table AS [Table]
         ON [Table].EffectiveDate = CA1.LastEffectiveDate
```

Comment: hi @adrianm, Just to know, can you please explain why did you use cross apply in this case?

Comment: It is just an "easier to read" version of `ON [Table].EffectiveDate = (SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate) ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return an `ActualDate` as required for the previous date if the `EffectiveDate` is a Weekend, however to include logic for bank holidays you will need to define these in a table and then add more logic to the below.

```
SELECT Name, Value, EffectiveDate, 
CASE WHEN datename(dw,EffectiveDate) = 'Saturday' 
     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, EffectiveDate)
     WHEN datename(dw,EffectiveDate) = 'Sunday'
     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, EffectiveDate)
END AS ActualDate
FROM Stock 
WHERE Name = 'IBM' 
AND EffectiveDate BETWEEN '20151231' AND '20160105'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect solution but this does the trick.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  value decimal(10, 4),
  EffectiveDate datetime
)
INSERT INTO @table
  VALUES (1, 'IBM', 200.0000, '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000')
  , (2, 'IBM', 201.4500, '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000')
  , (3, 'IBM', 201.0000, '2016-01-05 00:00:00.000')
  , (4, 'IBM', 202.0000, '2016-01-06 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @MinDate datetime = '20151231',
        @MaxDate datetime = '20160105';

SELECT
  id,
  (CASE
    WHEN Data.Value IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP (1)
        value
      FROM @table AS T1
      WHERE T1.EffectiveDate < Data.FinalDate
      ORDER BY FinalDate DESC)
    ELSE Data.value
  END),
  FinalDate
FROM (SELECT
  id,
  name,
  value,
  (CASE
    WHEN EffectiveDate IS NULL THEN Date
    ELSE EffectiveDate
  END) AS FinalDate
FROM @table T
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
  Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b) H
  ON T.EffectiveDate = H.Date) Data
ORDER BY finaldate
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna.. I hope you agree Adrian's response is a perfect solution.

Comment: Yup. that's the reason I've +1'd it